# What does this sql mean

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO MAPPING_TBL ( G_ID, MR_ID, G_TYPE, G_NUMBER ) 
SELECT :G_ID AS G_ID, :MR_ID AS MR_ID, :G_TYPE AS G_TYPE, :G_NUMBER AS G_NUMBER 
FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS 
         (SELECT G_ID, MR_ID, G_TYPE, G_NUMBER 
          FROM MAPPING_TBL 
          WHERE G_ID = :G_ID2 AND 
                MR_ID = :MR_ID2 AND 
                G_TYPE = :G_TYPE2 AND 
                G_NUMBER = :G_NUMBER2 )
```

Could anyone explain what does this sql actual doing? especially what does this

```
SELECT :G_ID AS G_ID, :MR_ID AS MR_ID, :G_TYPE AS G_TYPE, :G_NUMBER AS G_NUMBER 
FROM DUAL
```

sql do,  thanks.

Comment: It might help if you format it in a readable manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "conditional insert."

The statement is INSERTing a user-supplied record into a table `MAPPING_TBL` if that record does not already exist in the table.  In MySQL this is accomplished as an 'INSERT IGNORE'.  In contemporary Oracle one could use 'MERGE INTO' to the same effect.

The `SELECT :G_ID AS G_ID ... FROM DUAL` is a way of specifying a tuple of values, in this case parameterized values from the calling program.  (If you for instance SELECTed 1, 2, 3, 4 FROM DUAL, you'd get those values back in a row.  In this case, the calling program is supplying :G_ID and so on at query execution time.)

Answer (score 0):

It is just a syntax of `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement. To make it more simple, take this example below

```
INSERT INTO table1 (colA, colB, colC)
SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM table2
```

What it does is, Whatever rows that are `SELECT`ed from `table2` will be `INSERT`ed on `table1`.

[See for more info: **Oracle [INSERT INTO...SELECT]**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT :G_ID AS G_ID, :MR_ID AS MR_ID, :G_TYPE AS G_TYPE, :G_NUMBER AS G_NUMBER 
FROM DUAL
```

The semi-colon means the user will be prompted to enter those values. They are like parameters that are expected to be filled in at run-time